# Why are the 'xx packages can be updated' lines repeated twice?

Tags: 12.04, server, updates, login

When I logged in to my Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit server this morning over SSH, I saw this at the end of the 'welcome' screen:

```
  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

18 packages can be updated.
5 updates are security updates.
18 packages can be updated.
5 updates are security updates.


*** System restart required ***
Last login: Thu Mar 27 14:59:24 2014 from 192.168.0.7
me@server1:~$
```

I'm used to seeing 'xx packages can be updated, yy updates are security updates', but I've never seen those lines repeated twice. I'm absolutely sure it isn't a terminal scrolling/overwriting issue. The issue persists after a reboot.

Is this bad? How can I make it only show once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/1146170). It will be gone if you upgrade to 14.04.

Comment: 14.04 isn't out yet, correct?

Comment: That is correct; however, there is, as of today, a beta version available that probably has the patch applied.

Comment: @Undo 14.04 arrives on April (17?) I think.